How to make lean 4's rw tactic rewrite at a given position of ocurrence?
I am learning lean 4 and find it sometimes necessary to rewrite a specific instance of a term, but couldn't figure at how to do that.
In a fake example below, the rw tactic seems to always rewrite the first instance of a function definition (Nat.factorial), even though I'd like to rw the second instance of Nat.factorial:
example (n:ℕ) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  rw [Nat.factorial, Nat.factorial]
  sorry

I tried rw [Nat.factorial  at 2] and a few other options trying to rewrite the 2nd instance. But it's not the right syntax.
I can probably repeat the rw many times over to get to the 2nd instance of the function symbol on the right hand side. But this seems wrong.
Is there a mechanism in Lean 4 to rewrite at a specific position (and at that position only)?

You can use the conv tactic to "move" precisely into the part of the goal that you'd like to rewrite:
example (n : Nat) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  conv =>
    rhs  -- move to the right hand side of the equality
    rw [Nat.factorial]
  /-
    n : Nat
    ⊢ (n + 12).factorial = (10 + n + 1 + 1) * ((10 + n + 1) * (10 + n).factorial)
  -/
  sorry

The conv tactic has a wide variety of subcommands to explore expressions, you can read its documentation here.  For instance, rather than "moving" to the part of the equality that you specifically wanted to rewrite, you could have searched for a pattern instead:
example (n : Nat) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  conv =>
    pattern (_ + n + _).factorial
    rw [Nat.factorial]
  /-
    n : Nat
    ⊢ (n + 12).factorial = (10 + n + 1 + 1) * ((10 + n + 1) * (10 + n).factorial)
  -/
  sorry


Alternatively, you can explicitly tell rw which occurrences you want to rewrite:
example (n : Nat) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  rw (config := { occs := .pos [2]}) [Nat.factorial]
  /-
    n : Nat
    ⊢ (n + 12).factorial = (10 + n + 1 + 1) * ((10 + n + 1) * (10 + n).factorial)
  -/
  sorry

or which occurrences you don't want to rewrite
example (n : Nat) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  rw (config := { occs := .neg [1]}) [Nat.factorial]
  /-
    n : Nat
    ⊢ (n + 12).factorial = (10 + n + 1 + 1) * ((10 + n + 1) * (10 + n).factorial)
  -/
  sorry


Thanks! for my env, (4.3.0), the conv tactics worked nicely,  while the rw (config ...  ones gave an error message: failed to rewrite using equation theorems for 'Nat.factorial'Lean 4. But I guess this is a version/environment issue on my end.

@tinlyx Lean 4.3.0 is getting outdated, the latest version being Lean 4.10.0. It's not a problem per se, but since lots of features are being added, if you stick to an old version, advice you can get on this kind of forum might not apply.

If you are ok with Mathlib (which I assume you are since your MWE uses factorial), you can use nth_rw:
import Mathlib.Tactic

example (n:ℕ) : Nat.factorial (n + 12) = Nat.factorial (10 + n + 2)  := by
  nth_rw 2 [Nat.factorial]
  /-
  n : ℕ
  ⊢ (n + 12).factorial = (10 + n + 1).succ * (10 + n + 1).factorial
  -/
  sorry

(There is also nth_rewrite which doesn’t try rfl at the end, similar to rewrite.)
See https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/3987/122 for a list of tactics in Lean 4 and Mathlib.

Thanks for the help. I tried above in a separate file in Lean 4 4.3.0, but nth_rw or the import statement took forever to load. The system keeps saying "busily loading". (I waited for about 30min). I am not sure if this is normal.

It is likely that you aren’t downloading the mathlib cache.  That is an orthogonal matter to this tactic.  You can ask another PA.SX question or go to the lean Zulip.
